# Passing ManagedObject IDs across contexts

Tags: ios, core-data

Scenario:

I'm dealing with 2 viewControllers each with it's own context (same thread). I'm trying to pass the managedObject's objectID from MOC2 -> MOC1, via a delegate method. Fine, did that, it ***seems*** to be passing the ObjectID.

Here's the problem...from MOC1 (the delegate) I get a pointer to the new object via `[self.localMOC objectWithID:thePassedID]`. I run an NSLog on the found object, the log describes it, it seems to be found. Now when I try to find it in the updated fetched results controller it cannot be found even though it shows the object in the table view which is using that same results controller.

Here are the log statements...
The object via objectWithID: `<Account: 0x6b11f90> (entity: Account; id: 0x6db44b0 <x-coredata:///Account/t5F84827D-E710-4331-A462-FCA1A0D335102> ; data: <fault>)`

The results controller object: `<Account: 0x6b1fc50> (entity: Account; id: 0x6b50250 <x-coredata://84B6642A-9C80-451F-BED4-52952EDFC43C/Account/p9> ; data: <fault>)`

It seems as one is a permanentID and the other is a temporaryID, as well as completely different memory addresses.

Any clues as to what I am doing wrong?

Below is the flow:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a redesign I utilized the iOS5 parent/child MOC's. I still don't totally understand why the object ID's, even though they were permanent ID's, returned different objects between contexts. It obviously had something to do with it's merging even though I refetched data after a full save. Hopefully the inner workings of core data will gradually make more sense to me as time goes by. Thanks for the suggestions though.

Answer (score 1):

Each managed object context should be registered as an observer of the "did save" notification (NSManagedObjextContextDidSaveNotification) from the other context, so that it can merge the changes from the other context when it saves using `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:`
.

Comment: Well I know MOC 1 is updating because the new managed object (or some form of it) would not show up in the table view & fetched results controller. Plus I need to use the delegate method in order to pass the ObjectID.

Comment: Maybe there's updating, and _updating_? If you have two separate contexts and make changes, you have to get the data synced somehow, how are you currently doing this?

Comment: via NSManagedObject's Reset method. I thought ObjectID was specific to each managed object, and it was mainly used to get reference to that object. How else would one retrieve that object if there is no "ID" value? What's confusing me is that the object claims to be found in the context.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* that the two different forms of the ObjectID indicate that the first one (that doesn't end in `/p9` means it's been inserted but not yet saved. Are you certain it was at that point? You can usually back that up by checking inside the .sqlite file that your core data is backed by (caveat being that this is implementation detail) and use sqlite3 to `select * from Z<nameOfCoreDataEntityHere> where z_pk = 9;`

Answer (score 0):

Before you get the objectID from a new object,
use obtainPermanentIDsForObjects method its NSManagedObjectContext.
it would get you a perm id without waiting until the save.